# Redirecting users to a URL if a variable consists of spaces

Tags: php

If the variable below consists of no characters, just any number of spaces, I would like to redirect the user to a URL using `header("Location: URL"); exit();`.

How can I do that?

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(strlen(trim($comment)) == 0) header('Location: URL');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways:

```
if (trim($var, ' ') == '') {
    // $var consists of only spaces
}

// or

if (str_replace(' ', '', $var) == '') {
    // $var consists of only spaces
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the \s identifier for PCRE, this will also catch tabs and such:

```
if (preg_match('/^\s+$/', $comment) { ... }
```

[Edit] Or, if you want to also catch totally empty strings:

```
if (preg_match('/^\s*$/', $comment) { ... }
```

Comment: I think `preg_match` is a little over the top when a simple string function like `trim` could be used to have the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
!trim( $_POST['comment'] ) && header( "Location: URL" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str_replace(" ", "", $comment) == "")
{
  header("Location: URL");
  exit();
}
```